# How to show custom values on measure aggregation? (Weight average measure without weight factor)

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssas

Our source data looks like this (on excel spreadsheets, effectively there are a lot more columns, but this illustrates our issue):

```
Year   Institution   Weight AVG
2000   B1            13.90%
2000   B2            11.09%
2000   U1            11.73%
2000   U2            11.27%
2000   Total 2000    12.77%
2001   B1            14.24%
2001   B2            10.72%
2001   U1            11.77%
2001   U2            10.80%
2001   Total 2001    12.90%
```

In my first try I migrated all data except the Totals, then I used a simple average to aggregate the Weight AVG measure, but as we all know that is not the correct value of the aggregation. If we had the weight factor we could create a custom measure that aggregates correctly.

What we would want to achieve is to show the corresponding totals when aggregating some dimensions, in this case Time dimension (**not the default ones like sum, count or even simple average, but the real Weight AVG totals**):

```
Year   Weight AVG
2000   12.77%
2001   12.90%
```

In case we try to see the Institution dimension the measure should show a blank value as there are no Institution Total on the source data:

```
Institution  Weigh AVG
B1           -
B2           -
U1           -
U2           -
```

As far as I can see, I need to store every total that is present on the source and override the default aggregation to show what we want, but **how to store it (tables-relationship), and how to design the cube accordingly?**.

This would also need to work with more columns, for example if I add an Inst.Type with its corresponding totals:

```
Year   Inst.Type  Institution Weight AVG
2000   Type B     B1          13.90%
2000   Type B     B2          11.09%
2000   Type B     Total B     11.02%
2000   Type U     U1          11.73%
2000   Type U     U2          11.27%
2000   Type U     Total U     11.03%
2000   Total 2000             12.77%
2001   Type B     B2          14.24%
2001   Type B     Total B     14.24%
2001   Type U     U1          10.80%
2001   Type U     U2          10.30%
2001   Type U     Total U     10.50%
2001   Total 2001             12.90%
```

We could see more aggregations on the cube depending on the dimensions that are visible for example:

```
Year   Inst.Type  Weight AVG
2000   Total B    11.02%
2000   Total U    11.03%
2001   Total B    14.24%
2001   Total U    10.50%
```

as well as (again):

```
Year   Weight AVG
2000   12.77%
2001   12.90%
```

Hope that I made myself clear about, thanks for any input provided.